# Creating a multi-step form using a ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I am attempting to create a multi-step ModelForm using a library called [FormWizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#how-to-work-with-modelform-and-modelformset). However, I am having difficulty getting the results I want.

> **Work Flow**

```
User clicks on create patient link
User opens patient form
User inserts patient data
User submits form
if form is invalid:
    redisplay form with error 
if form is valid:
    move to next form 
    enter symptom data
    submit form
if form is invalid:
    redisplay form with error 
if form is valid:
    move to next form 
    enter disease data
    submit form
if form is invalid:
    redisplay form with error
if form is valid:
    User is redirected to general form that has patient + symptom + disease information.
```

> **View that will create the multi-step ModelForm**

```
class ConsultationCreate(SessionWizardView):

    instance = None

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = Patient
        return self.instance

    template_ = 'data/multi_form.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.instance.save()


def process_form_data(form_list):

    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    logr.debug(form_data[0]['NIS'])
    logr.debug(form_data[1]['identity'])
    logr.debug(form_data[2]['identity'])

    return form_data
```

> **This is the error it produces**:

```
ValidationError at /patient/create
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered.']
```

#### The code

> **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from data.views import IdentityList, IdentityCreate, IdentitySpecific, ConsultationCreate, MultiStep
from data.forms import  SymptomForm, DiseaseForm, IdentityForm

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^patient/$', IdentityList.as_view(),  name = 'data_patient_list'),

        url(r'^patient/create$', ConsultationCreate.as_view([IdentityForm, SymptomForm, DiseaseForm]),  name = 'data_patient_create'),

]
```

> **models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.shortcuts import reverse
    import datetime
```

> Creates Patient database

```
class Patient(models.Model):

    NIS =models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True )
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null = True)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    email_address = models.EmailField()

    CHOOSE = 'The patient is'
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    personGender = ((CHOOSE,'The patient is'),(MALE, 'Male'),(FEMALE,'Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=personGender,default=CHOOSE)

    born = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)
```

> Creates Symptom database

```
class Symptom(models.Model):

    identity = models.CharField('Name of symptom', max_length = 80, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = '')
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(Patient,  through = 'Consultation')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % ( self.identity )
```

> Creates Disease database

```
class Disease(models.Model):

    identity = models.CharField('Name of disease', max_length = 80, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 5000, default = '')
    symptom = models.ManyToManyField(Symptom)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % ( self.identity )
```

> Consultation model is the intermediate model

```
class Consultation(models.Model):
    patient_identity = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    patient_condition = models.ForeignKey(Symptom)
    patient_disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
    patient_treatment = models.ForeignKey(Treatment)
    consultation_date_and_time = models.DateTimeField('visitation date and time', auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)

    # Use get_absolute_url to access single page model objects that possess a Canonical Uniform resource locator
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('data_patient_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

> **views.py**

```
from data.models import Treatment, Symptom, Disease, Consultation, Patient
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect, render_to_response
from django.views.generic import View
from data.forms import IdentityForm
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
```

> Class based view for patient list

```
class IdentityList(View):
    template_ = 'data/patient_list.html'
    def get(self, request):
        patient_list = Consultation.objects.all()
        return render(request, self.template_, {'patient_list':patient_list})
```

> Class based view for patient detail

```
class IdentitySpecific(View):
    model = Consultation
    template_ = 'data/patient_detail.html'
    def get(self, request, pk):
        patient_consult = Consultation.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return render(request, self.template_, {'patient_consult':patient_consult})
```

> Class based view for multi-step modelform

```
class ConsultationCreate(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None
    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = Patient
        return self.instance

    template_ = 'data/multi_form.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.instance.save()
```

> Function process_form_data using to process form data in
>   ConsultationCreate view

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    logr.debug(form_data[0]['NIS'])
    logr.debug(form_data[1]['identity'])
    logr.debug(form_data[2]['identity'])
    return form_data
```